# Wire to board component ID

Tags: pcb, identification, component-selection

I need help identifying this component.  It is used to attach wire or ring terminals to the board.

The screw is an M4x10 for size reference.  The pad width is roughly 10mm.

It seems to be a "U nut", but I can't find anything related.

[image]

Comment: From the picture it isn't clear how large the component is. Can you edit the question to include any dimensions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question, please let me know if more information is needed.  I have spent an embarrassing amount of time searching for this